# Иностранные имена. Эван или Юэн?

Tags: имена-собственные

Иностранное имя: Эван Макгрегор или Юэн Макгрегор (англ. Ewan McGregor)? Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант *Эван* является транслитерационным. Согласно практической транскрипции, правильным вариантом передачи имени является *Юан*. Не менее близким к фактическому произношению является вариант *Юэн*.

Comment: А на первый взгляд то же имя "Иван".
Спасибо.